# how to add margin or padding to the vaxis title in google line chart

Tags: java, php, google-visualization

i am using google line chart. I have the following code

```
// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {
'packages': ['corechart']
});


var options, data, chart;

 $(function () {


// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

var tweets_table = $('#tweet-table');


function getData() {
    // Create array to hold our values for data table
    // Each key is an array which represents a "row" of data
    var values = [];

    // get our values
    $('#tweet-table tr').each(function (i, v) {

        // Create a new "row"
        values[i] = [];

        // Get either th or td and loop
        $(this).children('th,td').each(function (ii, vv) {
            if ($(this).is('td.tweet-count')) {
                // if we're looking at a numeric column be sure
                // to pass a integar to the Chart API
                values[i][ii] = parseFloat($(this).html());

            } else {
                // otherwise just get the text string
                values[i][ii] = $(this).html();
            }
        });
    });

    return values;
}

function drawChart() {
    var values = getData();

    // Create the data table.
    data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(values);

    // Set chart options
    options = {

        'width': '100%',
        'height': 500,
        fontSize: 16,
        fontName: 'Arial',

        tooltip: {isHtml: true},

        titlePosition: 'none',
        colors: ['#000'],
        areaOpacity: 0.1,
        pointSize: 15,
        pointShape: "circle",


      chartArea: { width: '90%', },
      lineWidth: 5,
      legend: {
            position: 'none'
        },

        hAxis: {
           textStyle: {
                fontSize:'16',
                color:'#555555',
                fontName: 'Arial'
                },


            title: "Years" , direction:1, slantedText:false, slantedTextAngle:90,
        },
        vAxis: {
            textStyle: {
                fontSize:'16',
                color:'#555555',
                fontName: 'Arial'
                },
            titleTextStyle: {color: "#000",bold: "true",italic: "false", margin: "200px"},
            title: "Total saldsfses",
            minValue: -1 , 
            textPosition: 'out',
            gridlines: {
                color: '#ddd',
                 count: 6
            },
                baselineColor: '#522fa1',
        },


    };

    var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({prefix: '', negativeColor: 'red', negativeParens: true});
    formatter.format(data, 0); // Apply formatter to first column

    var formatter2 = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ fractionDigits: 5});
    formatter2.format(data, 1);



    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}


// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
});


$(window).smartresize(function () {
  chart.draw(data, options);

});
```

and my output is

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhsXz.png)

Now, i want to move the vaxis title to the top. Means, i would like to apply

```
margin-top:-20px;
```

or

```
 top:20px
```

like this for the v axis title "Total saldsfses".

How to do this? any one please help

Comment: there are no standard options to adjust the placement of the title, you could add your own html and remove the title from the chart, or try to adjust the placement using javascript when the chart's `'ready'` event fires

Comment: Thanks for reply.. i will check.